# Converting more columns into different types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like as follows:

```
date           time_h     Checked     Verified
2018-03-10    21:10     TRUE         TRUE
2018-03-19    03:20     FALSE        TRUE
2018-04-04    12:03     TBC          FALSE
...
```

I have been trying to convert the strings to the following formats:

- date and time_h to date and time objects;
- Checked and Verified to boolean values.

After putting all text in lower case, I have tried as follows:

```
bool = {'true': True, 'false': False}

df['Checked']=df['Checked'].map(bool)
df['Verified']=df['Verified'].map(bool) 

df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
df['time_h']= pd.to_datetime(df['time_h']).dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

However, when I check using dtypes, the outputs show all the columns as objects (so no change has been applied). 
Where am I doing wrong? How could I also include the TBC in the TRUE boolean value (saying TBC = TRUE)?

**Edit:**

An example of nan in my code within column `time_h` is `NaN` (string format, as it comes from a csv file). 
After replacing 'NaN' value using

```
df['time_h'] = df['time_h'].replace('NaN', np.nan)
```

I get:

```
<bound method Series.isnull of 0      nan
1      nan
2      nan
3      nan
```

but when I use

```
t = df['time_h'].str.split(':', expand=True).astype(int)
df['time_h'] = pd.to_timedelta(t[0], unit='h', errors='coerce') + pd.to_timedelta(t[1], unit='m', errors='coerce')
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nan'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For converting to `bool` columns, you can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [707]: import numpy as np

In [704]: df.Checked = df['Checked'].astype(str).replace({'(?i)True|TBC': True, '(?i)False|nan': False}, regex=True)
In [704]: df.Verified = df['Verified'].astype(str).replace({'(?i)True|TBC': True, '(?i)False|nan': False}, regex=True)

In [706]: df.dtypes
Out[706]: 
date                object
time                object
Checked               bool
Verified              bool
```

For `date` column, use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

In [706]: df.dtypes                   
Out[706]: 
date        datetime64[ns]
time                object
Checked               bool
Verified              bool
```

For `time` column, you can use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
In [714]: t = df['time'].str.split(':', expand=True).astype(int)
In [716]: df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(t[0], unit='h', errors='coerce') + pd.to_timedelta(t[1], unit='m', errors='coerce') 

In [717]: df.dtypes
Out[717]: 
date         datetime64[ns]
time        timedelta64[ns]
Checked                bool
Verified               bool
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mayank Porwal, for your help. Almost everything was correctly converted, except for time. I have got this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nan'`. Not all the columns have a value for time (actually most of them are empty)

Comment: `np.where(df.Checked.eq('TRUE'), True, False)` this converts `TBC` to `False` doesn't it?

Comment: @MayankPorwal, I am still getting that error, unfortunately.

Comment: @Math Is the `nan` a string or a proper `np.nan`? do this first: `df['time'] = df['time'].replace('nan', np.nan)`. Then run my `timedelta` commands.

Comment: I have got now this error: `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`. The `nan` values come from a csv  (string; I get these as the cell is empty in the document) and they are not a proper `np.nan`

Comment: @Math Can you share a few sample rows with `nan` values in your dataframe.

Comment: Look good already upvoted. You can try this `df[['Checked','Verified']] = df[['Checked','Verified']].replace({'TRUE':True,'FALSE':False,'TBC':True})` also.

Comment: @Mayank, I updated the question to include an example. The value is `NaN`, not `nan` in the dataframe (after importing it using `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: There is a problem with the boolean values as I am loosing information on the right values. After converting them, all the values are set to False.

Comment: @Math Like how?

Comment: The problem is in the order converting values-converting to lower case. I have not understood how to put all columns in lower case and transforming values in boolean. These are the unique values for `Checked`: `array(['TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TBC', nan], dtype=object)`. However, when I used the two lines of code you suggested, all the values seem to get only False

Comment: That should not happen. I have tested my code for values `TRUE and TBC`. These will convert to boolean `True` and rest to boolean `False`. Please make sure there are no spaces after these strings in your df.

Comment: @Math There could be issue in the way you were checking for boolean values. My older solution would have worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct idea, but you need to use [**`astype`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) instead for the `boolean` type

```
df['Checked'] = df['Checked'].astype(bool)
df['Verified'] = df['Verified'].astype(bool)
```

As for the datetime you can use the [**`to_datetime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to do that

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['time_h'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_h'], format='%H:%M')
```

And then you can manually convert the `time_h` to `time`

```
df['time_h'] = df['time_h'].map(lambda x: x.time())
```

which will convert the type into a `datetime.time` object

Edit: if you have missing/invalid elements, that will cause the `to_datetime` to generate a `pd.NaT` object, you can handle it like this

```
df['time_h'] = df['time_h'].map(lambda x: x.time() if pd.notna(x) else np.nan)
```

here I'm converting it to an `np.nan` object (need to `import numpy as np` before) or you can leave it as is if you want using

```
df['time_h'] = df['time_h'].map(lambda x: x.time() if pd.notna(x) else x)
```

The full `time_h` part would be

```
df['time_h'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_h'], format='%H:%M')
df['time_h'] = df['time_h'].map(lambda x: x.time() if pd.notna(x) else np.nan)
```

Comment: Thank you @Jimmar. However, the format of time_h includes also the date. How could I remove it?

Comment: @Math I've updated my answer and added a convertion for the time

Comment: I have got this error: `ValueError: NaTType does not support time`

Comment: @Math that's because of the missing items, I've added an edit to handle that too

Comment: still now working and I am really not understanding why: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'time'`

Comment: just to be clear, you still have to do the `pd.to_datetime` step before doing the last part

Comment: I think the issue is because seconds are missing. Trying to do as follows: `df['time_h'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_h'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time`, it gives me `datetime.time(8, 52)`, but I would like to have 8:52. Also, I would like to understand how to easily check the values that are not `NaT`

Comment: @Math if you have different formats then you might need another step before this to convert them all into the same format. to filter out the `NaT` (or `np.nan`) you can use `df[df['time_h'].notna()]` which will return a dataframe without the `NaT` elements.
I believe that this would deserve it's own question though